# NSFileManager instances changing other instance's currentDirectoryPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I am subclassing NSFileManager in an iOS app to add some additional behaviours. While doing that, I ran into an issue that I can demonstrate without subclassing.

In summary, I create one instance of *NSFileManager*, change its *currentDirectoryPath*, print it, then create another instance, set its *currentDirectoryPath* to something else and I end up with the same *currentDirectoryPath* on both instances.

This is how to replicate this behaviour:

```
NSString * pathA = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"directoryA"];
NSString * pathB = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"directoryB"];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:pathA withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:pathB withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];


NSFileManager * fileManagerA = [[CCFileManager alloc] init];
[fileManagerA changeCurrentDirectoryPath:pathA];

NSLog( @"fileManagerA.currentDirectoryPath = %@", fileManagerA.currentDirectoryPath );  // outputs pathA, as expected


NSFileManager * fileManagerB = [[CCFileManager alloc] init];
[fileManagerB changeCurrentDirectoryPath:pathB];

NSLog( @"fileManagerB.currentDirectoryPath = %@", fileManagerB.currentDirectoryPath );  // outputs pathB, as expected
NSLog( @"fileManagerA.currentDirectoryPath = %@", fileManagerA.currentDirectoryPath );  // outputs pathB, why?
```

I've tried both SDK 7.1 and 8.1 on iOS 7 and 8 with the same results.

Comment: [NSFileManager defaultManager] is a singleton.

Comment: @danh isn't defaultManager the singleton?

Comment: @danh I think the issue is that changeCurrentDirectoryPath changes the setting for the entire process, not only that instance.

Comment: sorry, i should have read more carefully.  Can you prove you have two distinct instances by comparing the pointers: fileManagerA== fileManagerB, or NSLog(@"%p vs %p", fileManagerA, fileManagerB);

Comment: @danh, yeah they're different. "0x7964ad80 vs 0x79673dd0" - I think I've found the reason though. I guess currentDirectoryPath is more of a process-wide setting than an instance property.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the [documentation for NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/changeCurrentDirectoryPath:).

> All relative pathnames refer implicitly to the current working
>   directory. Changing the current working directory affects only paths
>   created in the current process.

The *CurrentDirectoryPath* is changed for the entire process and not just that instance of NSFileManager

Comment: That's consistant with `man 2 chdir` and POSIX behaviors. The path is changed for the whole process (including calls to open(), ...)

Comment: @Antzi indeed. I was under the incorrect impression that this was a property that NSFileManager would use as a "base" for its paths, but it's more of a gateway to the present working directory.